# Trying to convert HTML files to EML

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, thunderbird, gmail, thunderbird-addon

I am trying to import some messages from my old mail client to thunderbird v24.3 (so that they will sync into gmail).  I have all the messages saved as .html files as this is the only option I was given on export from that mail client.  I have tried to find a converter that will convert these files to eml so that I can view them in thunderbird but I am yet to find such a tool on the web.  Does anyone know how I can convert html to eml (or msg or pst, and then I can use PST Viewer) so that I can then gain access to these emails in thunderbird or outlook, or even directly into gmail?  I have both windows and mac so willing to try any options on those.
Thanks, 
Anna

Comment: Thjs probably ought to be migrated to https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ where the OP can ask for an app to do this

Answer (score 2):

I'm sure there must be other methods to export mail from Thunderbird. But if you really have only html files, you could use this script as a workaround. You will lose sender, recipient and subject, but the body will still be readable.

```
@echo off

for %%f in (*.html) do (
    echo Content-Type: text/html > %%~nf.eml
    echo. >> %%~nf.eml
    type %%f >> %%~nf.eml
)
```

Save the script with a .bat file extension, and place it in a directory containing the html files. Double click on it to generate an eml file for each html.

Answer (score 1):

You can't html files contain message text only. Not enough info to create EML files. You need additional headers like Subject, From, To, etc. I know there are a couple of EML export plugins for Thunderbird.